# Get material design color palette for my color

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I am trying to achieve the kind of color palette material design has for its different colors. But my particular color is not part of material design color. How do i get the different grades of my particular color like material design?

Comment: Visit [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html) for a list of MD colours and a downloadable swatch, and [here](https://www.materialpalette.com/) for a popular palette generator.

Comment: what i mean is that the color i want to use in my android app is not in the material color but i want to be able to generate the grades from 100 - 900 and the accent color of my own particular color

Comment: The color correspondence between screen colors and real word colors is a deep topic, and some people make their living at this calibration, e.g. [Pantone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone).  Many Android displays are very cheap, and even the expensive ones are not likely to have any kind of calibration.  You are unlikely to find any correspondence between colors in an application and any color you want to reproduce in the real world.  What is on your screen will always be an approximation, and Android AFAIK has no OS service for things like calibration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-app color palette, or go to this [Here](http://paletton.com/#uid=33r0u0knHV-3tX3iHX-sxS0BqLf). This is one of my favorite sites when looking for colors.

Comment: how is it really used?